# Image of a function:

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, notation, definition, polish-notation

Why is the image of a function written in the following way?

$$Im=\{ y \in Y\, | \, y=f(x) \quad 'for\, some' \, \,   x \in X\} $$

Why not '$\forall $' ?

Comment: If it were $\forall$, then you are saying that the image of $f$ is the set of elements in $Y$ which are equal to $f(x)$ for all $x$. So $y=f(x_1) = f(x_2) = ...$. Do you see why this is different from the image of a function?

Comment: @Helpplease I thought if $\forall$ was the case, it meant that $y=f(x) $ $\forall $ elements $x$ in the domain set $X$?

Comment: Bear in mind you are looking at each element of $Y$ individually in the definition.

Comment: @Helpplease I don't quite understand, sorry

Comment: @Helpplease understood, cheersm

Answer (score 0):

Take a function like $x^2$ from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$. Then $4$ is in the image, since for example $2^2=4$. That is to say, $\exists x\in\mathbb R,\ x^2=4$. Is it the case that $\forall x\in \mathbb R,\ x^2=4$ ?

Comment: Understood, cheers.

Comment: I thought it meant that all elements of the domain will be mapped, to an element of the co-domain $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, suppose it indeed said:

$$Im=\{ y \in Y\, | \, y=f(x) \quad 'for\, all' \, \,   x \in X\} $$

Now let's consider a simple function, e.g. $f(x) = 2x$, as defined over the natural numbers. So then:

$$Im=\{ y \in N\, | \, y=f(x) \quad 'for\, all' \, \,   x \in N\} $$

So, for a number like $2$ to be in $Im$, it would have to be true that $2 = f(1)$ *and* that $2 = f(2)$ *and* $3=f(3)$ *and* ...  This is not true, so $2$ is not in the image. In fact, with your definition, the Image will be completely empty, since $y=f(n)$ will not be true for *all* $n$.  But that is clearly not what we want. Conceptually, the Image clearly should be all the even numbers.

With the official definition it works. Since we have *some* number $x$ (namely, $x=1$) for which $f(x)=2$, $2$ will go in the image, as desired.